# How to insert foreign key value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have two tables `artist` and `arts`. `artistId` is the primary key in the `artist` table and it is the foreign key in `arts` table. I am using a stored procedure to insert data. First artist log in and then art info page is displayed where artist insert art info. I want that artist id to get inserted in arts table also when he inserts art info.

I tried this as:

Stored procedure:

```
if exists(select artistId from artist)
    insert into arts(name, description, artistId) 
    values(@name, @description, @artistId)
```

asp.net code:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",txtname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category",ddlcategory.SelectedValue);
```

It is not working.

I am new to stored procedure. Please help me to get the foreign key value. Or is there any other way?

Comment: What is the problem? How to call a stored procedure? Is there an error when calling your stored procedure?

Comment: yes.it is giving error as artistId can not be null

Comment: Can you show the definition of the proc?  I'm assuming you have `@artistId` as a param that you're not specifying.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the [Code Sample `{}`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VYd26.png) toolbar button—I've done it for you this time. You should also use tags to describe the technology the questions is about—I've tried some guessing about that.

Comment: create procedure arts(@artId int out,@name varchar(50),@category varchar(50),@artistID int)

Comment: The easiest question is do you have id data in the table? If not then it won't work...

Comment: yes I have id data in the table.after login only it will redirect to art info page.and when artist log in.there is an id present in database.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
if exists(select artistId from artist)
    insert into arts(name, description, artistId) 
    values(@name, @description, @artistId)
```

Shouldn't you be checking against who is logged in? Something like:

```
if exists(select 1 from artist where artistId = @artistId)
    insert into arts(name, description, artistId) 
    values(@name, @description, @artistId)
```

Aren't you trying to see if they exist before you insert art for them? Is that the issue? But like the comments above say, it is difficult to guess at the problem without more info.

Comment: yes.i need to check this.But it is giving me error as artistId does not exist in current context